# generate qr code in dart with qr.dart library

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code

I am trying to generate a qr code in flutter and upload to appwrite, this is the code:

```dart
QrCode qrCode = QrCode(4, QrErrorCorrectLevel.L)
  ..addData("${_nameController.text}-${_surnameController.text}-${_emailController.text}");
_qrCodeImage = QrImage(qrCode);
final qrImageBytes = Uint8Buffer();
final qrCodeSize = _qrCodeImage!.moduleCount;

for (var x = 0; x < qrCodeSize; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < qrCodeSize; y++) {
    final value = _qrCodeImage!.isDark(y, x)? 1 : 0;
    qrImageBytes.add(value);
  }
}
```

If I try to render the image I get an error "Failed to detect image file format using the file header.":

```
Image.memory(
     Uint8List.fromList(
     _qrCodeImageBytes!.toList()),
     width: 50,
     height: 50,
     fit: BoxFit.cover,
 ),
```

I want to store the image in memory and send upload qith a post request.

Comment: You would have to add a BMP file header at the start. One way is with the `bitmap` package. Use the `fromHeadless` constructor then `buildHeaded()`. See https://pub.dev/documentation/bitmap/latest/bitmap/Bitmap-class.html Note that this operates on an RGBA array, so instead of adding 1 or 0 you'd need to create groups of 4 bytes - presumably 255,255,255,255 and 0,0,0,0 respectively.